# Is it possible to use the ListContext in own components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to use the `dense` property of the ListContext to change the ListItemIcon fontSize. When I try to wrap the component in my own and import and use the context, the context is empty. The component is used inside as List/ListItem so it normally should have some values. I suppose it is because the ListContext is only use internally or am I wrong? In the case that I cannot use it what's a possible solution?

```
import React from 'react';

import MuiListItemIcon, {
  ListItemIconProps as MuiListItemIconProps,
} from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';

import ListContext from '@material-ui/core/List/ListContext';

const ListItemIcon: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<MuiListItemIconProps> = React.forwardRef(
  (props, ref) => {
    const { children, ...other } = props;

    const context = React.useContext(ListContext);

    return (
      <MuiListItemIcon ref={ref} {...other}>
        {context.dense ? React.cloneElement(children, { fontSize: 'small' }) : children}
      </MuiListItemIcon>
    );
  },
);

export default ListItemIcon;
```

```
// ...

<List dense>
  <ListItem>
    <ListItemIcon>
      <IcoCreate />
    <ListItemIcon>
  </ListItem>
  <ListItemText primary="Hello world!">
<List>

// ...
```

I expect the context to have a propery `dense` that is set to `true`, but the actual value is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListContext` is considered private. In the [Minimizing Bundle Size guide](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#option-1) you can find the following:

> Be aware that we only support first and second level imports. Anything below is considered private and can cause module duplication in your bundle.

Your import of `ListContext` is a third-level import (`List` would be second-level):

```
import ListContext from '@material-ui/core/List/ListContext';
```

While it "works" to import it, you are importing a duplicate copy of `ListContext` rather than the same one used by `List` which causes this to be a unique context type and is therefore unaffected by the setting of `ListContext` internal to Material-UI.

There are several ways you could achieve your desired result of dynamically adjusting the icon font-size based on whether or not it is within a dense list:

- Create your own `List` wrapper (in addition to your `ListItemIcon` wrapper) with its own context type that you use in your `ListItemIcon` wrapper.
- Use CSS (imitating what [SvgIcon does internally based on the prop](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.5.2/packages/material-ui/src/SvgIcon/SvgIcon.js#L47)) to change the font-size rather than using the `fontSize` property as shown in my example below.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import CreateIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Create";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const SmallIconIfDense = withStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    ".MuiListItem-dense & .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
      fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(20)
    }
  }
}))(ListItemIcon);
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <List dense>
        <ListItem>
          <SmallIconIfDense>
            <CreateIcon />
          </SmallIconIfDense>
          <ListItemText primary="Hello dense list!" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>
          <SmallIconIfDense>
            <CreateIcon />
          </SmallIconIfDense>
          <ListItemText primary="Hello second list item!" />
        </ListItem>
      </List>
      <List>
        <ListItem>
          <SmallIconIfDense>
            <CreateIcon />
          </SmallIconIfDense>
          <ListItemText primary="Hello non-dense list!" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>
          <SmallIconIfDense>
            <CreateIcon />
          </SmallIconIfDense>
          <ListItemText primary="Hello second list item!" />
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Small icon if in dense list]

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I assumed it was going to be something like you said in the first part but know I know for sure. As for the solution, I'm going to use the second one this way I'm not losing any functionality that the List provides.